# Create datetime object with HMS and YMD from individual variables

Tags: python

I have 6 variables for Hour,Minutes,Seconds,Date,Month and Year, how can i create a datetime object from these 6 individual variables

```
hour='10'
minutes='45'
seconds='23'
date='10'
month='12'
year='2017'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables have strings, so you have to convert to int first

```
hour='10'
minutes='45'
seconds='23'
date='10'
month='12'
year='2017'

import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(date),
    int(hour), int(minutes), int(seconds))
```